# Extract Numbers from Text File excluding Dates

Tags: python, regex

I have simple code which extracts numbers from a text file. It looks like this:

```
import re
codata = []
with open(r"filename.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        for i in re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', line):
            codata.append(i)
```

The text contains a lot financial data and also a lot of dates which I don't want. Is there an easy way to modify the code to exclude dates? The dates generally follow these formats (I'm using a specific date as an example for the format but it can be any date):

```
August 31, 2018
8/31/2018
8/31/18
August 2018
FY2018
CY2018
fiscal year 2018
calendar year 2018
```

Here is an example. I have a text file with the following text:

> "For purposes of the financial analyses described in this section, the term “implied merger consideration” refers to the implied value of the per share consideration provided for in the transaction of $80.38 consisting of the cash portion of the consideration of $20.25 and the implied value of the stock portion of the consideration of 0.275 shares of XXX common stock based on XXX’s closing stock price of $218.67 per share on July 14, 2018."

When I run my code I posted above, I get this output from `print(codata)`:

```
['80.38', '20.25', '0.275', '218.67', '14', '2018']
```

I would like to get this output instead:

```
['80.38', '20.25', '0.275', '218.67']
```

So I don't want to pick up the numbers 14 and 2018 associated with the date `"July 14, 2018"`. If I know that any numbers related to dates within the text would have the formats that I outlined above, how should I modify my code to get the desired output?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is pretty clear, but posting a few sample lines from the file with expected result is helpful.

Comment: you may have us a more complete example of input string?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand exactly what you want. But if you are just looking for numbers you can do this (and if it has a decimal, use float instead).

```
import re
codata = []
with open(r"filename.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        for i in re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', line):
            try:
                codata.append(int(i))
            except:
                continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that will match and remove your current set of dates:

```
import re

p = r"(((january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december) +[\d, ]+)|" + \
    r"((\d?\d\/){2}(\d\d){1,2})|" + r"((fiscal year|fy|calendar year|cy) *(\d\d){1,2}))"
codata = []

with open(r"filename.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        codata.append(re.sub(p, "", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE))

print(codata)
```

Output (assuming input file is the same as your provided date list):

```
['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your regex code to modify my original code like this and it does the trick:   with open(r"filename.txt") as file:  
 for line in file:  
  subdata.append(re.sub(p, "", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE))  
  for line in subdata:  
   for i in re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', line):  
    codata.append(i)

Comment: Great. Consider [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (✓) if it helped you resolve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the text sample I assume that every price starts with $ sign, in that case you are probably looking for the following regex:

```
r"(?<=\$)\d+\.?\d*(?= )"
```

the result would be:

```
['80.38', '20.25', '218.67']
```

Or in case you want the $ sign in your list the regex would be:

```
r"\$\d+\.?\d*(?= )"
```

and the result in that case:

```
['$80.38', '$20.25', '$218.67']
```

To clarify, the *(?<=\$)* means that our match needs to be proceeded by the $ sign, but the $ sign is not added to the output. (?= ) means that the price should be followed by space.

Comment: Thank you. It is not just stock prices; however, in my sample text I'd like to pick up the number 0.275 from "0.275 shares". So it's important to exclude numbers associated with dates and pick everything else rather than just include stock prices/financial data beginning with $.